# What does the acronym dst stand for?

Tags: node.js, naming

I'm using the fs module in node.js to create a read stream. In a example they name the return value from `fs.createReadStream()` "dst". What does it stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dst` is a common shorthand for "destination".

Answer (score 2):

You are finding out the joys of bad naming conventions.  There is no guarantee, but it could mean

```
daylight savings time
destination
distribution
```

and so on.

Try to figure it out based on the context of the code, and remind yourself to never use small variable names that can't be resolved to their purpose yourself.

Comment: Hells yes! seems to be a ton of these in the node.js world so far